# Server does not support base64_encode() and base64_decode() methods

Tags: php, jquery, canvas, png

i am using the following ajax/jquery code to save html5 canvas as png:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveAsImage.php",
        data:{data:data},
        type:"POST",
        success:function(r){
            $("#result").html(r);
        }

    });
```

The PHP code create .png file from the posted data with the following php code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img); 
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = date('Ymdhisa').'.png';
file_put_contents("img/".$fileName, $fileData);
    echo('<hr>Created Image is: <br><img src="img/'.$fileName.'">');
}
```

?>

Now, the actual problem is that my webserver does not support base64_encode() and base64_decode() functions, therefore, i am using the following method instead the base64_decode() method and commented out the base64_decode() method

```
 //$fileData = base64_decode($img);
   $fileData = rawurldecode($img);
```

Is there anyway through which i can do this?

Comment: can the server use the btoa and atob methods?

Comment: not sure- because i have not seen these methods when i printed the phpinfo().